# When is a (co)edge trivial in graph cohomology?

Tags: graph-theory, cohomology

Let $G$ be a connected graph and let $e$ be an edge in this graph. I would like to know if there are necessary and sufficient questions so that $e^{\vee}=0$ in $H^1(G)$? The question must be easy to experts but I did not find an explicit answer anywhere in literature and am not very much familiar with graph theory.

Comment: Is this equivalent to the edge being a bridge?

Comment: @Sam Hopkins. I don't know. What do you mean by a bridge?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_(graph_theory)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sam Hopkins's suggestion is right,  $e^{\vee}$ is trivial if and only if $e$ is a bridge.  (I'm assuming that you are taking $e^{\vee}$ to be an element in the simplicial cochain complex, so technically its sign depends on a choice of orientation of $e$).

Here is one argument.  We have that $e^{\vee} = 0$ if and only if it pairs to zero with every cycle $z \in H_1(G)$.  If $e$ is a bridge, then $G-e$ is a union of two connected components $G_1, G_2$, and $H_1(G)$ is spanned by cycles contained in either $G_1$ or $G_2$.  So $e$ pairs trivially with every element of $H_1(G)$.   Conversely, if $e$ is not a bridge, then $G-e$ is connected.  Choosing a cycle that crosses $e$ and then returns to its starting point through a path in $G-e$, we find an element $z \in H_1(G)$ with $e^{\vee}(z) = 1$.

Comment: @ Phil Tosteson. Thank you very much for your nice answer. I have another question: How about the sum of two co-edges? When do we have $e^{\vee}_1+e^{\vee}_2=0$ in $H^1(G)$? Thank you very much!